# Solve 500 internal server errors in load test VS Web / Load testing

Tags: asp.net

I doing a load test for an web application where i have to check for the load for 100 users. Once the user load comes to more then 50 i getting internal server error. Whats the solution for it. And should the test iteration in the report and the nomber of user has to be equal or not for correct result

Comment: The solution would be to fix the error... what is the error message?

Comment: Kept load pattern as step.
once it reach 40 - 50 user it show 
1-"500 - InternalServerError"
2-"No hidden fields were found in the response"
3-"Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.__EVENTTARGET' not found in test context"
4-"Request time out"

Comment: Errors 2 to 4 are just a resul from trying to parse the error page from error 1 as if it was a regular page. The error code 500 is shown for practically all server side errors, so you need to find out the details of the error message in the page.

Comment: Thanks for you reply...Let me findout the reason for "500 internal server error" and get back to you"